# Prevent the removal of the first line in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#

I want to prevent the user from deleting the first line  of a RichTextBox  making all the content to go up(he can still delete the content but stop the rest of it to  go up).
anyone have a good idea of how i can do it in a simple way ?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming WinForms, you can try using the SelectionProtected property:

```
richTextBox1.Text = "This is a protected text line." + Environment.NewLine;
richTextBox1.SelectAll();
richTextBox1.SelectionProtected = true;
richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.Length, 0);
```